# How to set text font in the table in Markdown (GFM)?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

How can I set the text font to be monospaced in the table if I use `<table>` HTML tag to create a form as following,

```
<table>
    <td>text here</td>
</table>
```

The markdown file will be rendered by GitHub, so using any extension supported by GFM is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some information [here](https://gist.github.com/dupuy/1855764)

> Mark *italic text* with one asterisk, **bold text** with two.
> For `monospaced text`, use two "backquotes" instead.

I believe custom CSS is not possible to add in.